# Some Font Awesome icons show, some do not

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome-5

I am accessing the OpenWeather API with ExpressJS by POST and AJAX, just to compare the 2 approaches.

Out of all things( all JS works), I am running into issue with the font awesome issues. Some are displayed, some are not.

I have tried everything placing the i tags inside all various elements, on their own etc. The results are inconsistent.

Anyway here is the markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous"> // this is the FA link

<input id="getIt" name="cityajax" type="text" class="ghost-input" placeholder="Enter a City" required>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
     <div class="textAlignCenter">
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
     </div>
     <div id="message"></div><span id="displaySky"> </span> // the icon here shows, but only after the class is added via jQuery

     <div class="wrapper">
       <div>
         <span class="humidLogo"></span> <i class="far fa-humidity" ></i> Current humidity:   <span class="apiHumidity"> % </span> // this icon does not show

     </div>

     <div>
       <span class="windLogo"></span> <i class="fas fa-windsock"></i>  Wind speed is:   <span class="apiWind"> km/h </span> //this icon does not show either

   </div>
     </div>
```

The relevant CSS is here, please don't lauch, this is what I have tried:-)

```
    .fa {
            color:violet;

        }
        .fas, .far {
            color:violet;

        }
        #displaySky {
          display: block;
          width:100%;
          margin: 20px auto;
          margin-bottom: 35px;
          text-align: center;
          color:violet;
          font-size:1.3em;
        }

        #message {
          display: block;
          width:100%;
          margin: 20px auto;
          text-align: center;
          color:black;
        }


        i {
          color: violet; font-size:2em !important;
        }
        .wrapper {
          margin:10px;
          border: grey 1px solid;
          padding: 30px;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
-webkit-align-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-line-pack: justify;
align-content: space-between;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
        }
```

And the JS, this should not have any effect, but the interesting this is the line where I add the icon class, that icon does show up, just run the ajax request by entering a city in the input field and you will see, the logo gets added properly.

I would be open to some feedback if this JS can be optimized a bit, I have tried to have different icons displayed based on the weather via EJS, but that was too messy, the variables do not have cross file scope, I simple prefer the jQuery way.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}  // ignore this


    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
```

var destination = ($("#getIt").val());

```
            $.post("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
            destination +
            "&units=metric&appid=15c9456e587b8b790a9092494bdec5ff",
            function (result, status, xhr) {

                var APIresponded =  result["main"]["temp"];
                var APIweather =  result["weather"][0]["description"];
                var sunGoing = result["sys"]["sunset"];
                var output = destination.capitalize();
                var humidValue = result["main"]["humidity"];
                var windy = result["wind"]["speed"];
                if (APIweather.includes("snow")) {
                  $('#displaySky').addClass('far fa-snowflake');
                }
                if (APIweather.includes("rain")) {
                  $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-cloud-rain');
                }
                if (APIweather.includes("overcast")) {
                  $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-smog');
                }
                if (APIweather.includes("sun") || APIweather.includes("clear")) {
                  $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-sun');
                }
                if (APIweather.includes("scattered")) {
                  $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-cloud-sun'); // All these if clauses work and add the icons
                }
                $("#message").html("The temperature in " + output + " is : " + APIresponded + " degrees. The sky looks like this: ");
                $(".apiHumidity").text(humidValue + " %");
                $('.humidLogo').addClass('fas fa-humidity'); // not working
                $('.apiWind').html(windy + 'km per hour');
                console.log(APIweather);
            }

            ).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " +
                xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            });
        });


    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("img").show(300);
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("img").hide(300);
    });
```

That is it, I have created a codepen:

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/qLgRvp?editors=1000

So, why are the icons not displayed? They do show up in the DOM when I check dev tools, but sized 0/0px. Tried to add the !important rule, did not work either.
What am I missing? I have read the similar threads on SO, but none would help with this. I do not think it is a flexbox issue either.

Answer (score 2):

Those particular icons, [fa-humidity](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=humidity) and [fa-windsock](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=windsock), are only available with the [Font Awesome Pro](https://fontawesome.com/pro) license. To fix this, you'd need to get a license, then [download](https://fontawesome.com/download) the Pro-related files.

Comment: Also, if you have the PRO license, make sure that you allow you domain in the settings on their page.

Comment: Lol, this took me hours of "debugging".
 
How do I knwo which ones are licenced?

And could I not just simply use the source code, as they all use the content attribute?

Oh well, how can I tell which ones are not licensed?

Comment: @ptts you need to check the site and you find this information. Read the duplicate link and you will get more details. There is also the version that you need to consider

Comment: Over on the left sidebar when searching, click "Free"; that'll show you which ones are available for use with the free license